# Show that $(\overline{\text{lin} A})^{\perp}=A^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have to show that $(\overline{\text{span} A})^{\perp}=A^{\perp}$ where $A$ is a subset of a Hilbert space.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By double inclusion. One inclusion is trivial. For the other one, use the continuity and the elementary properties of the inner product. Look lemma 3.2-2 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book.

Comment: $A\subset \text{span} A \subset \overline{\text{span} A}$ So $ (\overline{\text{span} A})^{\perp}\subset A^{\perp}$ But what about the second inclusion? I dont have access to that book..

Comment: It's a simple consequence of this property: if $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$, then $\langle x_n,y_n \rangle \rightarrow \langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: so I take $(x_n)$ from $A$ and what should I do?

Comment: You need to show that $A^{\perp}\subset (\overline{\text{span} A})^{\perp}$. Suppose $x$ is orthogonal to every element of $A$; How is the form of an arbitrary element of $(\overline{\text{span} A})^{\perp}$?, take one of them and check that it is orthogonal to $x$ (here, you should use the property mentioned above).

Comment: sorry, I cant get it ;/

Comment: Let $x$ be in $A^{\perp}$. If $y$ is in $(\overline{\text{span} A})$, there is a sequence $(y_n)$ of elements of $\text{span} A$ such that $\lim y_n=y$. It's easy to show that $x$ is orthogonal to every element of $\text{span} A$. So, by the property mentioned in my first commentary, $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x,\lim y_n \rangle=\lim \langle x,y_n \rangle=\lim 0=0$. Then, $x$ is in $(\overline{\text{span} A})^{\perp}$.